# Can GCM work with devices that does not find Google Play Services App in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm developing GCM in an app, but i can't get it work in two relatively new devices (LG P700 and Huawei y300) with Android 4.1.1. It works fine in other devices with 5.1 and 4.4. Also in one device with 4.1.2. **The two devices that can't get GCM working does not find google play services APP in Google play.**

The debugger shows this error checking if Google Play Services is available in the devices that can't find Google Play Services app in Google Play:

```
    06-23 06:32:11.100: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(23781): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
    06-23 06:32:11.110: W/System.err(23781): com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: Google Play Services not available
    06-23 06:32:11.110: W/System.err(23781):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzY(Unknown Source) 
06-23 06:32:11.110: W/System.err(23781):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzo(Unknown Source)
06-23 06:32:11.110: W/System.err(23781):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(Unknown Source)
06-23 06:32:11.120: W/System.err(23781):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
06-23 06:32:11.120: W/System.err(23781):    at com.mobimento.caponate.ad.AdManager$2.run(AdManager.java:570)
06-23 06:32:11.120: W/System.err(23781):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-23 06:32:11.600: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(23781): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 7329034
```

I'm sure must be a way to get GCM working in these devices. How can it be achieved?

Comment: Update Google Play Services on the device

Comment: The devices don't find Google Play Services App in Google Play

Comment: fail to find [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)?

Comment: your device have playstore?

Comment: @calvinfly When I check Google Play Services App in Google Play, the app does not appear.

Comment: @sasikumar Both devices have playstore, but I can't update Google Play Services

Answer (score -3):

Try to -

1. Update Google Play Services on the device
2. Open the Play Store at least once.
3. Then I ran my app again and it worked.

Comment: The devices don't find Google Play Services App in Google Play